# Customizing CalDAV for Selective Calendar Event Synchronization

Tags: calendar, icalendar, caldav

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I'm working on implementing a calendar solution using CalDAV, s*pecifically with Apple's implementation*. Our requirement is somewhat unique:

1. **Customers Book Appointments**: We need a system where customers can book appointments.
2. **Synchronization with Service Partners**: These appointments should then synchronize with the calendars of service partners.
3. **Privacy for Service Partners**: Our service partners have other appointments in their calendars that they don't want to share with us. So, we need a way to sync only the appointments booked by customers to our system.
4. **Partial Visibility in Sync**: For the service partners' self-added appointments, we want to see only a "blocked" or "busy" status in our calendar without any details of the appointment.

The challenge is setting up the CalDAV server to allow this selective synchronization and partial visibility. I am looking for guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this. Is this possible with standard CalDAV features, or would it require a customized solution? If customization is needed, what approach and tools would you recommend?

Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!